# Shortcut to close an instance of an app?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I have 5 instances of an app open right now. I want to close one such instance. I can obviously do it by clicking the red x button,  but I'm looking for a shortcut.

cmd + x doesn't work as it closes all instances

Comment: What is the name of the _application_ and how have you started multiple instances of it?

Comment: <Cmd + w> closes the current tab and if it’s the last/only one it closes current window as well (Safari, Mail etc)

Comment: @Aivar Paalberg, While what you said in your comment is generally true, nonetheless, it may not be applicable as the OP is using 5 separate instances of an unknown _application_ and it is also unknown how the separate instances where started. We may need that missing information to come up with a definitive answer.

Comment: Cmd/X is the command for Cut, not Quit - so it's a very unusual app indeed. We can't help if we don't know what it is & how you managed to launch 5 separate instances [which normally the Mac will not do without special methodology]

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of the equally confused - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402032/how-to-close-1-n-app-instances

Comment: @user3439894, I totally agree, therefore I wrote a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: What version of MacOS? Does using _Command + Tab_ to highlight/switch between the different instances and then _Command + q_ not work?